# Всем привет.Кто-нибудь знает как вывести сервер UBUNTUв глобальную сеть.Через роутер

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, веб-сервер

Тупо какие настройки и где прописать.То что выложено в гугле-не катит.Серв не выходит в нет.Сервер расположен на Virtualbox,на ноуте(учебный).Или тыкните где почитать норм мануал.На локалке работает.

Comment: Читайте в сторону настройки сети в VirtualBox (для хоста) маршрутизации и iptables (для сервера) и port forwarding'а (для маршрутизатора).

Comment: Ну вроде как надо для начала статический айпишник приобрести, а дальше уже из виртуалки на физическую тачку порты пробросить. Я не админ, точно не скажу, но думаю, что примерно как с докером история. Но без белого айпи в интернет не выйти.